# Is it possible when developing a facebook app to remove permissions and start again? I need to change my scope and keep getting errors

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am new to this Facebook coding game so have stumbled upon a fault that I think only I may be getting. I initially wanted to allow the user logging in to manage their pages, however as an after thought, the client wanted their users to be able to post to their individual pages as well.

So, I added the publish_stream permission to the scope, but am stuck with just getting Facebook has an error.

Do i have to deactivate myself from the app first a la the point on the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Code attached, any help would be great:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => $this->app_id,
        'secret' => $this->secret,
    ));

    $s = setting::findAppSettingSpecific('social','facebook');

    // exit;
    $facebook->setAccessToken($s);
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    $dia_url = 'http://localhost/social/accept/';
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params = array('redirect_uri' => $dia_url,'scope' => 'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
    if($user == 0) {


    }
    else
    {
        echo ("<script> top.location.href='".$login_url."'</script>");
        echo 'Facebook Loves Us';
        return true;
    }
```

It is working on Localhost, just in case someone points that out, however only started calling errors when adding an extra permission.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

(1) Use the [Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), select your app on the top right select box, change the method to DELETE and in the path put *me/permissions*.
This will remove all of the permissions you granted the app.

(2) If the app is bookmarked then in your facebook homepage hover the app name on the left bookmarks panel, on it's left an edit icon appears, click that and then *Edit Settings*, there you can remove some individual permissions.

(3) In facebook on the top right click the arrow that faces down, in the menu click *Privacy Settings" and in that page click the *Edit Settings* of "Apps and Websites" there you can control the apps you use.

---

## Edit

(4) You can remove individual permissions with a DELETE request to /me/permissions with an extra parameter of permissions=publish_stream for example

Thanks to @Igy who pointed out the 4th option.

Comment: Also, 4, you can remove individual permissions with a DELETE request to /me/permissions with an extra parameter of `permissions=publish_stream` for example